# Laravel 5.7 Request tipo de archivo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

me está sucediendo algo raro, quiero asegurarme de que el usuario seleccione un archivo correcto y no pueda subir cualquier cosa, para ello utilizo el request mimes, según la documentación oficial de laravel 5.7

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-mimes

Mi código es el siguiente: (El archivo se llama **AnexoRequest.php**)

```
case 'POST': {
    return [
      'descripcion'        => 'nullable',
      'user_id'            => 'nullable|exists:users,id',
      'clasificacion_id'   => 'required_if:anexo_providencia,"Anexo"',
      'expediente_id'      => 'required|exists:expediente,id',
      'username'           => 'nullable',
      'url'                => 'nullable',
      'fecha_vto'          => 'nullable',
      'anexo_providencia'  => 'nullable',
      'files'              => 'mimes:xls,xlsx,zip,jpeg,pdf,jpg,png,doc,docx,gif|required_if:anexo_providencia,"Anexo"',
                    
   ];
}
```

El campo se llama files porque pueden subir varios adjuntos

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="files[]" multiple />
```

El problema es que cuando quiero insertar un nuevo registro seleccionando un archivo que está entre los permitidos, me arroja un error de tipo de archivo, osea entra en funcionamiento el request, lo cual es raro porque estoy seleccionando un archivo permitido.

Que puede estar pasando ?

En el Controller la función store la tengo de la siguiente manera, les pongo el encabezado nada mas

```
public function store(AnexoRequest $request)
{
```

Agrero el resultado de dd($request->all()) cuando quito la condición

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "OQyrGPoRvFBWO128SZZBNWR6DLntIg1nq8u3YaA4"
  "anexo_providencia" => "Anexo"
  "expediente_id" => "27"
  "ex" => "prueba 6"
  "clasificacion_id" => "1"
  "fecha_vto" => "22-03-2022"
  "descripcion" => "srfgewrgfaewrfg"
  "files" => array:1 [▼
    0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1546 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "TITULO WEB CAMIONETA.pdf"
      -mimeType: "application/pdf"
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "/tmp"
      filename: "phpZ6p56N"
      basename: "phpZ6p56N"
      pathname: "/tmp/phpZ6p56N"
      extension: ""
      realPath: "/tmp/phpZ6p56N"
      aTime: 2022-03-22 19:43:10
      mTime: 2022-03-22 19:43:10
      cTime: 2022-03-22 19:43:10
      inode: 3150229
      size: 23394
      perms: 0100600
      owner: 1000
      group: 1000
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
      link: false
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: podrías hacer un dd($request) para ver efectivamente que datos estan llegando en tu controlador.

Comment: Puse el dd($request) como primer linea en el controller en la función store, pero el request se ejecuta antes

Comment: Esto es lo que llega en files

Comment: +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#1542 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "files" => array:1 [▼
        0 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#33 ▼
          -test: false
          -originalName: "TITULO WEB CAMIONETA.pdf"
          -mimeType: "application/pdf"
          -error: 0
          path: "/tmp"
          filename: "phpzGRjrQ"
          basename: "phpzGRjrQ"
          pathname: "/tmp/phpzGRjrQ"
         ... borro sino no entra en el comentario
          type: "file"
          writable: true
       ...

Comment: entonces coloca el dd en el Request, la idea es ver que exactamente esta llegando, ya que a primera vista no hay error en la regla de validacion, pero quizas del lado del formulario no se esta enviando correctamente.

Comment: Tambien podrías fijarte si tu formulario esta definido para enviar archivos; enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta Javier colocando lo que llega, y con respecto al formulario tiene esto {{ Form::open(['route' => ['anexo.store'], 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) }} y anda bien porque antes de agregar eso en el request el formulario funcionaba correctamente

Comment: por eso me llama mucho la atención, digo voy a preguntar quizás hay algo que no estoy viendo

Comment: No sé porque en el dd la extensión llega vacía, y no llega un mimes, sino más bien llega un mime/type

Comment: exactamente cual es el error?, o sea que dice el mensaje de error?

Comment: otra que veo, podrias no enviar el archivo como array?, o sea, solo name="files"

Comment: efectivamente es por el array, https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-multiple-files-images-upload/

Comment: Hola el error que arroja es ell que le defino en el request, archivo no permitido. Le quite el array lo deje para un sólo archivo y persiste el error

Comment: Si era el array. MUCHAS GRACIAS a TODOS por participar